# Remote Debug Windows Forms project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I have simple one Windows Forms project with one Main form in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, on my dev Windows 8.1 Pro PC. I also have second computer (name: REMOTEPC) with Windows 8.1 Pro and installed Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor 2013 Update 4. I have configured Windows Authentication and firewall settings. I have configured project properties for Debug to use remote machine to REMOTEPC:4018 and in logs I see that user REMOTEPC\username connected. I use same local and remote paths (C:\proj\bin\debug\myprogram.exe) and have manually copied all files from directory.

Now I got error:
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program (C:\proj\bin\debug\myprogram.exe). The MSCSMON.EXE does not appear to be running on the remote computer.

As I understand it needs only one TCP 4018 port and can not find a mistake. I have read MSDN info about this, but can not figure out why its not working. Is the remote debugging for Windows Forms or WPF possible at all ?

Comment: Are the 2 machines connected to an AD domain? Remote debugging does not really work otherwise.

Comment: both of them are standalone (workgroup) and when connecting it asks for windows credentials, and then I can see that authentication passed in Monitor app log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use to configure firewall / port forwarding if needed, for both TCP 4018 and TCP 4019. I was missing one port (4019) and now it works without a problem.